# conditional statement in react native image source

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.5",
```

i want to use local images and uri whenever i want, i wrote a component to do this for me according to props sent to it.
but it seems conditional statement doesn't work in **react native image**, or require doesn't work with dynamic strings.

```
const CustomImage = ({ img, url, size, rounded, style, onClick }) => {
    alert('imageeeeeeeeeeee', typeof (img));
    let REQURE_STATEMENT= null;
    if (img !== null) {
        REQURE_STATEMENT= require('./../src/assets/images/close.png');
    }
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.85} onPress={()=> onClick() }>
            <Image
                source={url === null ? REQURE_STATEMENT: { uri: url }}
                style={{ width, height, borderRadius: rounded, backgroundColor: 'red', ...(style) }}
                onPress={() => console.log('clickkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk')}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>

    );
};
```

i even tried

```
let path= `./../path/${imageName}`
 <Image source={url === null ? require(path): { uri: url }}/>
```

but it fails with this error:

```
why not support error: bundling failed: Error: error: bundling failed: Error: components\common\CustomImage.js:Invalid call at line 42: require(image)
    at C:\Users\ui4\Desktop\react-git\mbz-mobile-app\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:317:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\ui4\Desktop\react-git\mbz-mobile-app\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:75:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\ui4\Desktop\react-git\mbz-mobile-app\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:95:9)
```

Comment: Try this - let path= "./../src/assets/images/close.png"; let uri = { uri: url };
 <Image source={url === null ? require(path) : uri }/>

Answer (score 0):

you can do it outside the `Image` component like this:

```
const CustomImage = ({ img, url, size, rounded, style, onClick }) => {
  alert('imageeeeeeeeeeee', typeof (img));
  let REQURE_STATEMENT= null;
  if (img !== null) {
    REQURE_STATEMENT= require('./../src/assets/images/close.png');
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.85} onPress={()=> onClick() }>
      {url === null ? (
        <Image
          source={REQURE_STATEMENT}
          style={{ width, height, borderRadius: rounded, backgroundColor: 'red', ...(style) }}
          onPress={() => console.log('clickkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk')}
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          source={{ uri: url }}
          style={{ width, height, borderRadius: rounded, backgroundColor: 'red', ...(style) }}
          onPress={() => console.log('clickkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk')}
        />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still struggling...

```
<Image source={dynamicUrl ? {uri: dynamicUrl} : require(defaulPathtString) />
```